# Creating Excel Files using VB2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a form with 1 button to create an Excel file on my desktop.

I get error message:

> NullReferenceException Was Unhandled
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object

and it highlights the code:

```
WB = excelapp.workbooks.add
```

I did add the reference "Microsoft excel 14.0" and my full code is below:

```
imports excel = microsoft.office.interop.excel

dim excelapp as excel.application
dim WB as excel.workbook

sub button1()

WB = excelapp.workbooks.add
excelapp.visible=true

end sub
```

Comment: You haven't initialised your `excelApp` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Missing New on your Excel instance for starters:

```
Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add()
Dim xlWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = CType(xlWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1"), Excel.Worksheet)

xlWorksheet.Cells(1, 1) = "data in first cell"
xlWorksheet.SaveAs(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) & "\" & "Test.xlsx")

xlWorkbook.Close()
xlApp.Quit()

xlApp = Nothing
xlWorkBook = Nothing
xlWorkSheet = Nothing
```

You should probably put this in Try/Catch/Finally block to catch errors in case you run into issues, but mostly because if the program doesn't continue properly finish that code block, an EXCEL.EXE will remain open in your task manager, as well as whatever Excel file it was accessing will be "in use by another program" when you try to access/modify/delete it.

Answer (score 0):

just add one line, then it'll work

```
imports excel = microsoft.office.interop.excel

dim excelapp as excel.application
dim WB as excel.workbook

sub button1()

    excelapp = new excel.application

    WB = excelapp.workbooks.add
    excelapp.visible=true    
end sub
```